# retrieve section from UIButton in Header view in section in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have insert a UIButton in the header of the UITableView in every section, i want know if it's possible when pressed retrieve the section number, i add the button in this way:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 309, 70)];

UIButton *markAllYes = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[markAllYes setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mini_seen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[markAllYes setFrame:CGRectMake(95, 35, 31, 31)];
[markAllYes addTarget:self action:@selector(markAllYesPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[headerView addSubview:markAllYes];

return headerView;
}
```

Comment: use tag like this markAllYes.tag = section and access with the use of the markAllYes.tag button tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `tag` property of your UIButton.

```
markAllYes.tag = section
```